# Gerrit system groups not created after install

Tags: gerrit

Gerrit (2.13.6)

I've completed the installation according to 
https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/install-quick.html

Created a couple of users, applied keys, etc.

I only see two groups listed in the 'List groups'
"Administrators" and "Non-Interactive Users"

However the documentation indicates that there are the following 
system groups: Anonymous Users, Change Owner, Project Owners, Registered Users which I do not see anywhere; Are they supposed to have been created during the installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually these groups don't really "exist", I mean you will not see them in the People > List Groups lists. They're kind of "virtual" groups... you can't add/remove people to/from them. For example, when someone logs in Gerrit he/she is automatically added to the "Registered Users" group, every Gerrit user (logged or not) belongs to the "Anonymous Users" (the group name was not well chosen).

They exist to be used to grant project permissions.

Comment: Thank you; is that also true of 'Project owners' and 'Change Owner'

Comment: Exactly, in the context of the project and the change.